# How do I resolve Compilation Error in Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, compiler-errors, ribbon

I keep on getting a Compilation Error user-defined type not defined.

The error is on "Public globalRibbon As IRibbonUI"

I added more references under tools to try and resolve the issue but I am still getting the compilation error

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public globalRibbon As IRibbonUI


Public Sub onRibbonLoad(ByVal ribbon As IRibbonUI)
  Set globalRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

Public Sub RibOpenForm(control As IRibbonControl)
  DoCmd.OpenForm (control.Tag)
End Sub

Public Sub ControlEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
    Select Case control.ID
        Case "Primary"
            If CurrentProject.AllForms("Primary").IsLoaded Then
               enabled = False
          Else
                enabled = True
          End If

        End Select

  End Sub
```

I expect to be able to set custom ribbon controls however it is not working.

Comment: What references have you added?  And which version of Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems something is wrong with COM references in your VBA environment. You may try to install the latest updates and/or repair Office.

> Compilation Error user-defined type not defined

1. Open up the VBA editor and go to Tools | References.
2. Scroll down until you see the following entries:

   - Microsoft Access X.0 Object library.
   - Microsoft Office X.0 Object library.
3. If you have multiple versions, use the latest version.

Both entries should be selected.

Comment: I tried doing that before posting but I guess I did not save it. That resolved the issue.